# How can I register a decorator using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, ioc-container

How can I register a decorator class when using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection as the container?

When registering my types in the following way (similar to Castle Windsor) I get a "System.InvalidOperationException : A circular dependency was detected" error on resolving the IMyService type:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyServiceDecorator>();
```

Decorator registration does not appear to be supported out the box but is there any way to add support or get round the problem?

Comment: See: https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/340

Comment: @Steven thanks, that post helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Registering in the following way using the [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) project appears to get the decorator to resolve correctly:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
services.Decorate<IMyService, MyServiceDecorator>();
```

Decorate is an extension method in the namespace: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions within the Scrutor project.

Comment: Decorate is not a method that Microsoft provides.

Comment: @Steven yep, in my hast I forgot to mention Scrutor. Well spotted.

Comment: I suppose no decoration Microsoft supports.
Check SimpleInjector for this

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use Scrutor or just curious how one could implement decorators without it.

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService>(serviceProvider =>
{
    var concreteMyService = services.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ServiceType == typeof(IMyService));
    var concreteMyServiceType = concreteMyService.ImplementationType;
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyServiceDecorator>(
        serviceProvider,
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, concreteMyServiceType));
});
```

Here are some tricks I've used here.

`AddTrasnient` has an overload that accepts a factory.

`IServiceCollection` is just a collection of [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) so you can register `MyService` somewhere in different library and make it internal (it's a style of programming I prefer) and when registering `MyServiceDecorator` you can look up `IMyService` implementations instead of relying on `MyService` directly.

Another trick is [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) Given an `IServiceProvider`, this method lets you partially provide the constructor parameters for a Type, and lets the `IServiceProvider` "fill in the blanks". This is done for a reason that `MyServiceDecorator` can have more parameters than just `IMyService` instance.